# Running Mocha tests with SailsJS and Superagent

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sails.js, mocha.js, superagent

I'm currently writing an app using SailsJS. What has been done so far works as expected when tested 'manually', but doesn't when tested with Mocha.

I tried to follow [SailsJS testing guide](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/testing), calling the test with npm:

```json
[...]
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js",
  "debug": "node debug app.js",
  "test": "mocha test/bootstrap.test.js test/unit/**/*.test.js"
},
[...]
```

My test directory structure is as follows:

```
test
├── bootstrap.test.js
├── mocha.opts
└── unit
    └── controllers
        └── UserController.test.js
```

boostrap.test.js:

```js
var Sails = require('sails');
var sails;

before(function(done) {
  Sails.lift(function(err, server) {
    sails = server;
    if (err) return done(err);
    done(err, sails);
  });
});

after(function(done) {
  Sails.lower(done);
});
```

UserController.test.js:

```js
var request = require('supertest');

describe('UsersController', function() {

  describe('#logout()', function() {
    it('should respond with a 401 status because nobody is logged in', function (done) {
      request(sails.hooks.http.app)
        .put('/user/logout')
        .expect(401, done)
    });
  });

  describe('#signup()', function() {
    it('should create and log in an user', function (done) {
      request(sails.hooks.http.app)
        .post('/user')
        .send({
          firstname: 'foo',
          name: 'bar',
          email: 'foo@bar.com',
          sex: true,
          password: 'foobar',
          birthdate: '01/01/1991',
          phoneNumber: '+33 3 10 10 10'
        })
        .expect(200, done)
    });
  });

  describe('#logout()', function() {
    it('should log out an user', function (done) {
      request(sails.hooks.http.app)
        .put('/user/logout')
        .expect(200, done)
    });
  });

  describe('#login()', function() {
    it('should respond with a 404 status because credentials are invalid', function (done) {
      request(sails.hooks.http.app)
        .put('/user/login')
        .send({
          email: 'bar@foo.com',
          password: 'barfoo'
        })
        .expect(404, done)
    });
  });

  describe('#login()', function() {
    it('should log in an user', function (done) {
      request(sails.hooks.http.app)
        .put('/user/login')
        .send({
          email: 'foo@bar.com',
          password: 'foobar'
        })
        .expect(200, done);
    });
  });

  describe('#login()', function() {
    it('should respond with a 401 status because user is already logged in', function (done) {
      request(sails.hooks.http.app)
        .put('/user/login')
        .send({
          email: 'foo@bar.com',
          password: 'foobar'
        })
        .expect(401, done);
    });
  });
});
```

Finally, here is my output when I call *npm test*:

```
> sails@0.0.0 test /Users/fwoelffel/Dev/STOFMA
> mocha test/bootstrap.test.js test/unit/**/*.test.js



  UsersController
    #logout()
debug: false
debug: req.session -> {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"}}
info: Policy 'authenticated' disallowed to proceed to the next policy
      ✓ should respond with a 401 status because nobody is logged in (86ms)
    #signup()
debug: null === req.session.authenticated || undefined === req.session.authenticated -> true
debug: req.session -> {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"}}
info: Policy 'unauthenticated' allowed to proceed to the next policy
info: User foo@bar.com signed up and logged in.
      ✓ should create and log in an user (146ms)
    #logout()
debug: false
debug: req.session -> {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"}}
info: Policy 'authenticated' disallowed to proceed to the next policy
      1) should log out an user
    #login()
debug: null === req.session.authenticated || undefined === req.session.authenticated -> true
debug: req.session -> {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"}}
info: Policy 'unauthenticated' allowed to proceed to the next policy
info: No user matching bar@foo.com.
      ✓ should respond with a 404 status because credentials are invalid (66ms)
    #login()
debug: null === req.session.authenticated || undefined === req.session.authenticated -> true
debug: req.session -> {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"}}
info: Policy 'unauthenticated' allowed to proceed to the next policy
info: Found user foo@bar.com.
info: foo@bar.com credentials are valid.
      ✓ should log in an user (128ms)
    #login()
debug: null === req.session.authenticated || undefined === req.session.authenticated -> true
debug: req.session -> {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"}}
info: Policy 'unauthenticated' allowed to proceed to the next policy
info: Found user foo@bar.com.
info: foo@bar.com credentials are valid.
      2) should respond with a 401 status because user is already logged in


  4 passing (1s)
  2 failing

  1) UsersController #logout() should log out an user:
     Error: expected 200 "OK", got 401 "Unauthorized"
      at net.js:1419:10

  2) UsersController #login() should respond with a 401 status because user is already logged in:
     Error: expected 401 "Unauthorized", got 200 "OK"
      at net.js:1419:10



npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

To sum things up, I am testing an auth/unauth API. An below are the policies:

- When a logged in user tries to log in, the 'unauthenticated' policy should throw an error (401)
- When a logged in user tries to sign up, the 'unauthenticated' policy should throw an error (401)
- When an logged out user tries to log out, the 'authenticated' policy should throw an error (401)

I might be doing something wrong but I really can't figure what it is. Could you help to solve this issue?

If you need more information, please ask. You might find the code (without the tests, since they're failing) [on Github](https://github.com/ciaa-cnam/STOFMA).

Thanks for reading, have a nice day!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to elsaar, I changed my code to:

```js
var request = require('supertest');
var agent;

describe('UsersController', function() {

  before(function(done) {
    agent = request.agent(sails.hooks.http.app);
    done();
  })

  describe('#logout()', function() {
    it('should respond with a 401 status because nobody is logged in', function (done) {
      agent
        .put('/user/logout')
        .expect(401, done)
    });
  });

  describe('#signup()', function() {
    it('should create and log in an user', function (done) {
      agent
        .post('/user')
        .send({
          firstname: 'foo',
          name: 'bar',
          email: 'foo@bar.com',
          sex: true,
          password: 'foobar',
          birthdate: '01/01/1991',
          phoneNumber: '+33 3 10 10 10'
        })
        .expect(200, done)
    });
  });

  describe('#logout()', function() {
    it('should log out an user', function (done) {
      agent
        .put('/user/logout')
        .expect(200, done)
    });
  });

  describe('#login()', function() {
    it('should respond with a 404 status because credentials are invalid', function (done) {
      agent
        .put('/user/login')
        .send({
          email: 'bar@foo.com',
          password: 'barfoo'
        })
        .expect(404, done)
    });
  });

  describe('#login()', function() {
    it('should log in an user', function (done) {
      agent
        .put('/user/login')
        .send({
          email: 'foo@bar.com',
          password: 'foobar'
        })
        .expect(200, done);
    });
  });

  describe('#login()', function() {
    it('should respond with a 401 status because user is already logged in', function (done) {
      agent
        .put('/user/login')
        .send({
          email: 'foo@bar.com',
          password: 'foobar'
        })
        .expect(401, done);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the session is not being persisted, so a the user you loggedin in an earlier request won't be loggedin in a later request. Which is the way unit tests should be. So you'll have to ensure that the user is in the desired stated(logged in or out) before the test is run.

**EDIT** - You need use the same instance of the supertest agent to persist your session - https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/46#issuecomment-58534736

So just do this at the beginning of your tests, and use the same agent in all tests

```
var supertest = require('supertest');
    agent = supertest.agent(sails.hooks.http.app);

// the use the agent to test your endpoints
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thanks!